# Query running windows workflows in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, workflow, workflow-foundation-4

I have a scheduled job (in asp.net) which creates and runs several workflows using WorkflowApplication and its Run method. Since Run is an async method the job returns quickly after firing off the workflows in their own workflow thread, which is great!

However, I don't want the job to create and run new workflows before all previous workflows have completed (or failed). My question is thus, is there a way to query the workflow runtime for running workflows?

I am not using a persistant store in relation to my workflows as they don't need to be persisted.

Addition:
The (web) thread (web job) that starts the workflows will end its work before the workflows completes. A new  job thread spins up again a couple of minutes later, this thread needs to know the statuses of the previous' thread started workflows. If I write the tracking data (using tracking extension) to a DB I believe the 2.nd thread can query it, but I would rather avoid using DB. Is there a way to ask the workflow runtime if it is idle or active?

Comment: I've done this by blocking the calling thread using an AutoResetEvent (any kind of Mutex-like thread synchronizer works) that is Set() by the Completed or Idled callbacks.  Or, of course, you could just use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465567(v=vs.110).aspx which runs synchronously.  Depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You use the workflow tracking extension.  This reports on the state of workflows.  It's a push system so rather than query the workflow, you use a TrackingParticipant that signals your main thread when it detects the states you are looking for.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee513992(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: In relation to your Addition to the question, I do not know of a way to query the workflow in real time.  You could use a data structure in memory to hold the Tracking information but then it would be vulnerable to losing power or application shutdowm.  I usually throw the data into a small database like MongoDB or mySQL.